# Stabilizing Role Calling On Role Run

Tags: c#, azure

I have 14 worker roles and 6 of them are acting strange. Several of them say busy, stabizing role. Calling on role run. Is this a Microsoft issue or a coding problem?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly a code issue, not an Azure issue.  The role instances are Busy, which means they are not responding to the health probes from the host bootstrapper.  I would recommend going through the troubleshooting series at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx which walks through all the logs and troubleshooting techniques you can use to diagnose this issue.

Comment: Thanks! I did a restart and removed some scheduled tasks that caused technical issues.